# Запятая между причастием и прилагательным

Tags: запятые

> Выделяющиеся(,) особые слова, которые...

Какие правила есть на этот счёт?

Answer (score 3):

Однородные определения, выраженные прилагательными и причастиями и стоящие перед определяемым словом, отделяются друг от друга запятой: *Лена устроила ее в **просторной**, **пустой** комнате*; *И в эту минуту **сдержанный**, **мягкий**, **вежливый** Зощенко вдруг сказал мне с раздражением: «Нельзя лезть в литературу, толкаясь локтями*».

[https://orfogrammka.ru/пунктуация](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) § 4.10

Answer (score 3):

***Выделяющиеся, особые слова,*** которые...

В данном случае причастие **выделяющиеся** переходит в прилагательное, у него нет значения действия.

Отношения между определениями **однородные, сближенные по значению**, они раскрывают одну тему (яркие, заметные, выделяющиеся, особые слова).

Если не поставить запятую, то первое определение ***выделяющиеся*** будет относиться к словосочетанию ***особые слова,*** как будто среди особых слов мы находим выделяющиеся (а это неверно по смыслу).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря: особый — не такой, как все, выделяющийся среди прочих.

*Выделяющиеся* (одиночное причастие) и *особые* (прилагательное) выступают как синонимы, то есть как слова, близкие по значению, поэтому они являются однородными (произносятся с перечислительной интонацией).
Между однородными определениями, стоящими перед определяемым словом, ставится запятая.

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html)

*Именно среди духовенства с конца 17 века и на протяжении более 200 лет систематически вводились в употребление особенные, выделяющиеся и живописные именования людей.*